# Word for someone who always uses their head before making a decision?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for someone who always thinks about the consequences before making a decision?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please expand your question as [required](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for single-word-requests info. Hover over the `single-word-requests` tag and click 'info'.

Comment: Uhm, a wise person? Like me? ;)

Comment: I'm no native english speaker, but the first term that comes to mind is 'calculated'.

Comment: [Pragmatic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic): `relating to matters of fact or practical affairs often to the exclusion of intellectual or artistic matters :  practical as opposed to idealistic`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

[reflective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reflective) in the sense of: characterized by quiet thought or contemplation

There are a number of synonyms at the link.

Answer (score 2):

**Prudent** seems quite close to me.

> [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prudent)
>
> Acting with or showing care and thought for the future